# Chart-section issues

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, charts

I'm having issues with trying to code a chart section for a template. The desired result is this:[image]

And what I'm getting is this: https://codepen.io/Kestvir/pen/GEwMGP

```
  $(document).ready(function() {

  $('.chart-blue').easyPieChart({
    //your options goes here
    barColor: '#30bae7',
    scaleColor: false,
    lineWidth: 10,
    lineCap: 'circle',
    size: 150,
    scaleLength: 0

  });
  $('.chart-pink').easyPieChart({
    //your options goes here
    barColor: '#d74680',
    scaleColor: false,
    lineWidth: 10,
    lineCap: 'circle',
    size: 150,
    scaleLength: 0

  });

  $('.chart-green').easyPieChart({
    //your options goes here
    barColor: '#17c2a4',
    scaleColor: false,
    lineWidth: 10,
    lineCap: 'circle',
    size: 150,
    scaleLength: 0

  });


  $('.chart-orange').easyPieChart({
    //your options goes here
    barColor: '#eb7d4b',
    scaleColor: false,
    lineWidth: 10,
    lineCap: 'circle',
    size: 150,
    scaleLength: 0

  });



});
```

I'm using https://github.com/rendro/easy-pie-chart to code the charts.
Also, not only the chart it self, but also the procentages should be animated ( going from 0% to a specific % fast).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Phoenixy is correct. Here is a js fiddle where I edited only the first chart

https://codepen.io/carinlynchin/pen/zzMPEa

```
<div class="chart-blue" data-percent="90">
    <div id='test'>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, also, sorry for asking now, but maybe you might know, how to make the animation of the chart happen only when I scroll down to the chart section itself ? Because now when I get to it, the animation already has happened when I reloaded the page, but my goal is to make that animation happen only when I scroll to it, or pass it.

Comment: hackhands.com/carinlynchin

Answer (score 1):

Probably not the nicest solution, but this should work.
Give a < span > to the % value.

```
<div class="chart-blue" data-percent="90"><span>90%</span></div>
```

Do the same with the other colors as well.
Add this css:

```
.class-col-md-3 span {
    margin-left: 57px;
    margin-top: 68px;
    position: absolute;
}
```

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/eRQeGV